# When not to use gradient descent?

Tags: gradient-descent, moving-average

I am trying to understand whether application of Stochastic Gradient Descent(SGD) goes in every model where optimal parameter values are to be obtained?

Take for example, a hypothetical time series updated based on Exponentially Weighted Moving Average(EWMA):

`X_t` = `alpha` * `X_(t-1)` + (1 - `alpha`)*`X^_t`

Can I simply apply SGD to determine appropriate `alpha` here?

Thanks

Comment: What's the purpose of estimating alpha?

Comment: @williamchiu Consider the equation useful to predict X (denoted by X^t)? What best alpha can be used so the errors are minimized?